# Problem with launching turtlebot_gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04, with kernel 3.8.0-35-generic. My graphics card info: ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series], and I am using the Radeon driver.

I get an error while trying to run the following command from the turtlebot_simulator tutorial:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch

(I get a similar error while trying to run "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch" also)

This is what I get in the terminal window:

process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [13821]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [13840]
Msg Waiting for master.process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [13859]
[ INFO] [1404322766.629329135]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
Msg Waiting for master
[ INFO] [1404322766.636610011]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http:// 127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.227.80.208
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-9]: started with pid [13920]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-10]: started with pid [13926]
Floating point exception (core dumped)

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 13782, exit code 136, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/fastslam/.ros/log/cf107f7c-020f-11e4-bfba-e4115b24feb2/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/fastslam/.ros/log/cf107f7c-020f-11e4-bfba-e4115b24feb2/gazebo-2*.log

.............................

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:116] Failed to connect to master in 30 seconds.

[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 13787, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/fastslam/.ros/log/cf107f7c-020f-11e4-bfba-e4115b24feb2/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/fastslam/.ros/log/cf107f7c-020f-11e4-bfba-e4115b24feb2/gazebo_gui-3*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182446/problem-with-launching-turtlebot_gazebo/) by [tadityasrinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19383/tadityasrinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tadityasrinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19383/tadityasrinivas/) on 2014-07-07**:
Resolved the problem. The issue was with the graphics driver. Installing proprietary ATI drivers resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you check this page ( http://answers.ros.org/question/65402/gazebo-fail-to-connect-to-master-in-30-seconds-it-does-not-run-from-the-very-first-time/ )? Probably this answer solves your problem. Because Error message says Failed to connect to master in 30 seconds. Your problem has a relationship with gzclient and gzserver. I think so.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1